# Ubuntu Studio Installer - Option for Gnome Rebranding is not an option

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-studio

When you goto the Ubuntu Studio Installer webpage there is two entries on the screen shot for rebranding options.  When I ran the latest version of the Ubuntu Installer those last two options are in in the screen.

Comment: I assume the page you mean is https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/ but it's best if you're specific, and what do you mean by *latest* version?  and what release are you using?   You'll be offered what is available for your *unstated* release.

Comment: If the options aren't offered then very likely you AREN'T using Ubuntu or any official derivatives.